# Coordinates wrong format after change culture

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I display google map with markers on it.
When selected language is English it's ok, but when I change language map is not displayed and I think it is because `lat/lng` is written differently:

```
English: 44.012/22.098
Other: 44,012/22,098
```

What should I do in this case?
I get coordinates from database and store it in thees properties:

```
public double Longitude { get; set; }
public double Latitude { get; set; }
```

Here I get NAN, NAN

```
var c = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
```

Comment: Where is this lat/lng coming from? can you be more descriptive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google maps expects lat lng values in a format like this: `41.112469` So if your values contain comma character, replace them with a dot and create your `LatLng` objects with that value.

```
var lat = '44,012';
var lng = '22,098';
lat = lat.replace(/\,/g,'.');
lng = lng.replace(/\,/g,'.');
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I wonder now. Is it better maybe to use `string` type on backend side instead of `double` for longitude & latitude or this is bad practice?

Comment: It might be better to keep them as double values if you plan to make some kind of calculations with them. Other than that, it wouldn't make much difference.